# Changing the basis from $p$-basis to $k$-basis in standard quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, conventions, hamiltonian, normalization

if $$\hat p = \int dp |p\rangle p \langle p|$$ and I want to chage the basis to $|k\rangle$ it is correct to say that $\hat p$ is therefore equal to:
$$
\hat p = \hbar^2 \int dk |k\rangle k \langle k|
$$
since,
$p=\hbar k$ and $dp =\hbar dk$

also will this mean that the hamiltonian in this $|k\rangle$ basis and in the absence of a potential equal to
$$
\hat H = \int dk |k\rangle \frac{\hbar^4 k^2}{2m}\langle k|
$$

Comment: Assuming you are using a convention normalization (see link in my answer for more on this) then you have 2 too many factors of $\hbar$ in your final result. But, really the answer depends on how you define the $|k\rangle$, which you have left unsaid.

Comment: *conventional normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand a little on [hft's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/788005/83835), let's see how the definitions follow from the choices via the change of variables invoked in the OP.  Starting with the resolution of the identity, given by
$$
\hat{I} = \int dp\,\lvert p\rangle\langle p\rvert\,,
$$
in terms of (delta-function normalized) momentum states, we perform the change of variables $p=\hbar k$, resulting in
$$
\hat{I} = \int d(\hbar k)\,\lvert \hbar k\rangle\langle \hbar k\rvert
=\int d k\,\sqrt{\hbar}\lvert \hbar k\rangle\langle \hbar k\rvert\sqrt{\hbar}
\,.
$$
We then (with a possibly confusing abuse of notation) define the state
$$
\lvert k \rangle =\sqrt{\hbar}\lvert \hbar k\rangle\,,
$$
in which case
$$
\hat{I}=\int d k\,\lvert k\rangle\langle k\rvert
\,.
$$
Since this is the resolution of the identity, this guarantees that the states $\lvert k \rangle$ are delta-function normalized:
$$
\lvert k \rangle = \hat{I} \lvert k \rangle
=
\left(\int d k'\,\lvert k'\rangle\langle k'\rvert\right)\lvert k \rangle
=
\int d k'\,\lvert k'\rangle\langle k'| k \rangle
$$
which forces $\langle k'| k \rangle=\delta(k-k')$ if this is to be true for every state $\lvert k\rangle$.

With this definition, we also have that
$$
\hat{p} = \int d p \lvert p\rangle p \langle p\rvert
= \int d k\lvert  k\rangle (\hbar k)\langle k\rvert\,,
$$
and hence
\begin{align}
\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} &= \frac{1}{2m}
\int d k\lvert  k\rangle (\hbar k)\langle k\rvert
\int d k'\lvert  k'\rangle (\hbar k')\langle k'\rvert
=
\frac{1}{2m}
\int d k
\int d k'
\lvert  k\rangle (\hbar k)
\langle k| k'\rangle
(\hbar k')\langle k'\rvert
\\&=
\frac{1}{2m}
\int d k
\int d k'
\lvert  k\rangle (\hbar k)
\delta (k-k')
(\hbar k')\langle k'\rvert
=
\frac{1}{2m}
\int d k
\lvert  k\rangle (\hbar k)^2
\langle k\rvert\,,
\end{align}
which has the "right" number of $\hbar$'s.

Comment: It looks like you need to either remove the "3" from your $d^3 k$ and $d^3 p$ or use $\hbar^{3/2}|\hbar\vec k\rangle$ rather than $\sqrt{\hbar}|\hbar k\rangle$ in your k-ket definition. (OP asked about a one dimension system, but you are looking at a three-dimensional system, so we expect factors of $\sqrt{\hbar}^3$ in the various normalizations.)

Comment: This is because $d^3 p \to d^3 (\hbar k) = \hbar^3 d^3k$ not $\hbar d^3k$

Comment: @hft Oh yes, I'm not being careful about 1d to 3d.  I'll remove the $^3$.

Answer (score 2):

> if $$\hat p = \int dp |p\rangle p \langle p|$$ and I want to chage the basis to $|k\rangle$ it is correct to say that $\hat p$ is therefore equal to:
> $$
> \hat p = \hbar^2 \int dk |k\rangle k \langle k|
> $$
> since,
> $p=\hbar k$ and $dp =\hbar dk$
>
> also will this mean that the hamiltonian in this $|k\rangle$ basis and in the absence of a potential equal to
> $$
> \hat H = \int dk |k\rangle \frac{\hbar^4 k^2}{2m}\langle k|
> $$

The answer depends on what you mean by your $|k\rangle$ in relation to your $|p\rangle$.

I will use [the following notation and conventions](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Quantum_Mechanics_III_(Chong)/01%3A_Scattering_Theory/1.02%3A_Recap-_Position_and_Momentum_States) (see link for further details):
$$
\hat p|k\rangle = \hbar k|k\rangle
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{I} = \int dk |k\rangle\langle k|\;.
$$

Thus:
$$
\hat H = \frac{\hat p^2}{2m}
$$
$$
=\frac{\hat p^2}{2m}\int dk |k\rangle\langle k|
$$
$$
=\int dk \frac{\hat p^2}{2m}|k\rangle\langle k|
$$
$$
=\int dk \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}|k\rangle\langle k|
$$

---

**Update:**

It seems like it might be helpful to add some further discussion regarding normalization.

I think the best starting point is remembering one common definition of the delta function, namely:
$$
2\pi\delta(x - y) = \int dk e^{ik(x - y)}\;,
$$
where, n.b., there is a factor of $2\pi$ on the LHS.

Therefore, if you want to write:
$$
\mathbf{I}=\int dk |k\rangle\langle k|\;,
$$
you need to make sure that
$$
\langle x|k\rangle = Ae^{ikx}
$$
is normalized correctly. In particular you can choose
$$
A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\;,
$$
which is consistent with:
$$
\langle x|\mathbf{I}|y\rangle 
= \delta(x - t) 
= \langle x|\int dk |k\rangle\langle k||y\rangle 
= \int dk |A|^2e^{ikx-iky}
=\int \frac{dk}{2\pi}e^{ikx - iky}\;.
$$

Similarly, if you also want to write
$$
\mathbf{I} = \int dp |p\rangle\langle p|\;,
$$
this is doable too, but the normalization for the $|p\rangle$ has to make sense.

In particular, if we let
$$
\langle x|p\rangle = Be^{ipx/\hbar}
$$
then we have
$$
\delta(x-y) = \int dp |B|^2e^{ipx/\hbar - ipy/\hbar}
$$
$$
=\int \hbar dk |B|^2 e^{ikx - iky}\;,
$$
which means that we should choose
$$
B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\;.
$$

Thus, with these convention, we have:
$$
\mathbf{I} = \int dk |k\rangle\langle k | = \int dp |p\rangle\langle p|
$$
$$
\langle x|k\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikx}
$$
$$
\langle x|p\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{ipx/\hbar}\;.
$$